# what does it mean by those equations of random process?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

What does it mean by this notation $(1_Y)$ of random process,

$$ \Psi=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}1_{Y(X)\rangle s} $$ 
and 
$$ \Psi=\int 1_{Y(X)\rangle s} f(x) dx $$

where $s$ is a given threshold 
and $f(x)$ is the joint pdf of $X$.

Comment: Indicator function

Comment: this indicator indicates what ?

Comment: From Wiki: The indicator function of a subset A of a set X is a function

${\displaystyle \mathbf {1} _{A}\colon X\to \{0,1\}}$
defined as

${\displaystyle \mathbf {1} _{A}(x):={\begin{cases}1&{\text{if }}x\in A,\\0&{\text{if }}x\notin A.\end{cases}}}$

Comment: then it is binary function for a given limit or interval,

Comment: I think you mean $\mathbf {1} _{Y(X)>s}$ in the sum, and $\mathbf {1} _{Y(x)>s}$ in the integral.

Comment: like you explained in the last comment : 
it is the sum of the ones of the subset, 
in the integral : is the integration of f(x) when $1_Y$ is in the subset. 
 is this right !

Comment: Yes, since $f$ is the pdf of $X$, the second one is just $P(Y>s)$, and the 1st one is its discret version: the average proportion of time ($n \in \Bbb{Z}$) spent in $\{Y>s\}$.

Comment: the second part of the last comment is not clear !

Comment: isn't the n/N where n is the ones of the subest and N is the set ! 
then n/N is proportion $\in [0,1]$

Comment: Sorry I mistakenly added the word "average": I mean "the first sum is the proportion of time spent in $\{Y>s\}$".  From the last comment, I think you get the idea.  However, to estimate the 2nd one by simulation, you use the 1st one.  Since a multitude of experiments is carried out, you'll take the average to give a Monte-Carlo estimate.

Comment: I don't know for the second, it is not clear, 
if Y is more then s, then the output is 1, thus 
$$\Psi=\int 1_{Y(X)\rangle s} f(x) dx =\int f(x) dx $$
isn't like this !

Comment: You integrating *inside* the event $\{Y(x)>s\}$.

Comment: then f(x) belongs to the subset also,

Comment: In $\int f(x) dx$, the other case $\{Y(x) \le s\}$ is also included.

Comment: let me try to explain this in my understood, 
we integrate f(x) in the subset when the Y(X) is more then s, isn't same for P(Y more then s), in this case it is partition of the set, in other world like we integrate pdf for given inteval,

Comment: why $\{Y(x) \le s\}$ is included, since $\{Y(x) > s\}$

Comment: Because you're integrating on the whole real space in $\int f(x) dx$

Comment: I see for the second eq of my quetion that 
$$\Psi=\int 1_{Y(X)\rangle s} f(x) dx=\int_{s}^{inf} f(x) dx $$